# Unix, user authentication: How to authenticate with MD5-encrypted password?

Tags: unix, authentication, md5

I am working on a web-based system in a large organization with many users, while each user has certain permissions.

In order to enforce the user access and permissions, **I want each user to authenticate with his Unix username and password** in the login screen.

I don't want the passwords to be transferred in their original form between the client and the server - i.e. I want to send them encrypted to the server.

So the question is - whether it is possible to authenticate in Unix with username and password encrypted by MD5 function?

If not - is there another encryption function that is supported?

Comment: How is ssh involved here?

Comment: I was confused with `ssh` and `su`. .Removed ssh tag